# Is it a good idea to add tags for engines with low popularity?

Tags: discussion, tags

Whilst it would make people more aware of the game engine, would it really be of much use to do this? It could be considered as extra clutter, for example, if I added a tag referring to an engine that only I knew about, would anyone really care, let alone know the answer to any questions on that tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags are about categorization of on-topic subject domains for searching and filtering. They are not about advertising or otherwise "making people aware" of products, and so should not be added for that purpose.

If an individual question is *really about* some engine (and isn't just a more general problem that happens to be done *with* or *in* that engine), it's certainly appropriate to add the tag to that one question. Unless the engine in question is a private, proprietary product, which case it's pointless.

It would not be appropriate to go back through the question history and retroactively apply that tag to anything that looks remotely relevant.

Comment: When I add a tag that does not exist, I generally tag another question, just to make it so that there is not only one question with that tag, to prevent the tag from being removed by the system.

Comment: That's fair, in general, although I'm not personally convinced the engine-specific tags are really that great and need proliferation.

Comment: Yeah, if the questions are generic and not specific to the engine, in theory, there is not need to tag them. Same with the language tags, but we're kind of stuck with it.